# this.$vs.confirm (Vuesax) как это работает?

Tags: vue.js

Вопрос к знатокам Vue, у фрэймворка Vuesax для Vue, есть функция this.$vs.confirm , которая вызывает модалку и при нажатии да, выполняет колбек который в нее передается.

Вопрос в том, как можно реализовать что нибудь подобное самому?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Суть данной методы не является специфичной для vue.
Накрыть страницу div-ом (или любым другим элементом, каким только сможете:).
Посреди этого div-а нарисовать свой диалог.
div как бы лишает пользователя доступа к странице под ним, за счёт чего достигается модальность. Хотя этого не достаточно, поэтому "как бы".

Для реализации данной задумки в/на vue можно поступить следующим образом:

Создаём `plugin` в папке `src/plugins/ConfirmDialog`

Внутри создаём:

1. Компонент vue, который представляет окошко диалога
   `plugins/ConfirmDialog/ConfirmDialog.vue`

   ```
    <template>
      <div class="confirm-dialog-container">
        <div class="configm-dialog">
          <div class="header">{{ header }}</div>
          <div class="message">{{ message }}</div>
          <div class="buttons">
            <button @click="$emit('input', true)">Да</button>
            <button @click="$emit('input', false)">Нет</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'ConfirmDialog',
      props: {
        header: String,
        message: String,
      }
    }
    </script>

    <style>
      .confirm-dialog-container {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.53)
      }

      .confirm-dialog-container .configm-dialog {
        min-width: 300px;
        background-color: white;
        border-color: black;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: thin;
      }

      .confirm-dialog-container .configm-dialog .header {
        padding: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      .confirm-dialog-container .configm-dialog .message {
        padding: 40px;
      }

      .confirm-dialog-container .configm-dialog .buttons {
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: lightgray;
        text-align: right;
      }

      .confirm-dialog-container .configm-dialog .buttons button:nth-child(2) {
        margin-left: 15px;
      }

    </style>
   ```

С помощью стилей добиваемся того, чтобы контейнер диалога `confirm-dialog-container` полностью накрыл `body` страницы.

2. Собственно сам plugin
   `plugins/ConfirmDialog/index.js`

   ```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import ConfirmDialog from './ConfirmDialog.vue'

    export default {
      install(vue) {
        const root = new Vue({
          data() {
            return {
              visible: false,
              header: '',
              message: '',
              callback: null,
            }
          },
          methods: {
            onConfirmInput(event) {
              this.visible = false;
              if (this.callback) {
                this.$nextTick(() => { this.callback(event) });
              }
            }
          },
          components: { ConfirmDialog },
          render(h) {
            return h('div', {}, this.visible ? [ h(ConfirmDialog, { props: {
                header: this.header,
                message: this.message,
              }, on: {
                input: this.onConfirmInput,
              }}) ] : [])
            },
        });

        vue.confirm = function(header, message, callback) {
          root.header = header;
          root.message = message;
          root.callback = callback;
          root.visible = true;
        };

        root.$mount(document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')));
      }
    }
   ```

Плугин создаёт компонент `root`, который содержит ConfirmDialog.vue и обрабатывает события нажатия его кнопок, управляет его свойствами (заголовок, сообщение).
На странице создаётся элемент `div`, в который монтируется этот root.
Таким образом на странице создаётся `ещё одно vue-приложение`. root его корневой компонент, поэтому root:)

А в целевое приложение, добавляется метод `confirm`, предназначенный для вывода диалога.

Для активации/деактивации диалога используется свойство `visible` root. См. его метод `render(h)`

Теперь подключение и использование

3. Подключить plugin в главное приложение
   `main.js`

   ```
    import ConfirmDialog from './plugins/ConfirmDialog'
    Vue.use(ConfirmDialog);
   ```
4. Использование
   `components/MyComponent.vue`

   ```
    Vue.confirm('Требуется подтверждение!', 'Вы согласны?', (confirmed) => {
        if (confirmed) { // да
            ...
        } else { // нет
            ...
        }
    });
   ```

На самом деле это только создаёт видимость модальности.
Очень сложно сделать по-настоящему модальное окошко.
Например, нажимая `tab`, пользователь может легко переместить фокус под диалог.
Нужно предпринимать специальные меры против побега из модального окошка.